# Codename One: How to stream live video to YouTube Live

Tags: java, codenameone, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm developing an app which I need to **stream video** captured from the **Smartphone's video camera** (on iPhones and Android phones) directly to YouTube Live.

I looked into Codename One's Capture.captureVideo(ActionListener response) method which must wait for the video to be stopped, the file to be saved, and then the ActionListener is called. Obviously, this can't work work because the video has to be streamed to an output stream (to an URL given by YouTube Live API) on a continuous basis. Is there any other way to accomplish this? (What about any unofficial API, like method to override, to get the input stream from the camera?) If not, would Codename One consider providing this feature for a version upgrade as the market trend seems to be moving on live video streaming apps?

If it cannot be done with Codename One's API, then the only way is to write native code for Android and iOS. I've read the article integrating native API and using Freshdesk API as an example, so any pointers on how to integrate YouTube API for the purpose of streaming live video?

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/libraries
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a REST API within the list of API's although there is a JavaScript API which you might use to implement this. Alternatively you can use something like was done with the freshdesk API. You will need to embed the native view from the live broadcast, you can look at the implementation of [Google Maps](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) to see how we embedded that native widget.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! After much consideration, I think the easiest way is to open a webview (Display.getInstance().execute() is the right method to get a webview?) and then use HTML5 to stream to YouTube Live. The URL to stream to would be RMTP protocol, eg. "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2". What do you think?

Comment: Just to clarify: there are 2 problems which I need to solve for my app. First, it is to stream from the smartphone to YouTube Live using the RTMP protocol. Second, is it to view (ie. play) the videos from YouTube (I believe this is easy using Codename One's Media / MediaPlayer class).

Comment: It's possible that you can just grab the rtmp stream and place it into the media object. I'm not sure if that complies with the terms of service for youtube though. Notice this will only work on devices as the simulator probably doesn't support rtmp